# Windows Forms process animations

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, animation

I make some tests with C# and Windows Forms.
At the moment I am trying to implement some animations, for example display the current time or display a loading animation.
I looked around the internet but some solutions I found looked a bit ugly.
For example the most people create a Timer and refresh the animation at a specific frequency.
But I don't think thats the purpose of a timer...
So I found a second solution.
Simply register for the Application Idle event so I can update some animations and other processing stuff as part of the main application loop.
This sounds like a better solution.
Also I am wondering how I should request a redraw of some custom animated controls.
Simply call Invalidate() or Update() whats the recommend way?

**Whats the professional way of update and redraw such things like a timer or other animations of custom controls?**

Comment: Idle event does not sound better.

Comment: _I don't think thats the purpose of a timer_ What do you think is the purpose then and why do you think erverybody else is wrong? Hint: 'Professional' and 'winforms animation' do not go well together..

Answer (score 1):

There is a background worker,  you can read more about it here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Or you can use `async/await` - a `Task` based asynchronous approach 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx